# explaned algorithm Fingerprint Pore Extraction Based On Marker Controlled Watershed Segmentation

Tags: algorithm, fingerprint, feature-extraction

I try extract pore of fingerprint using algorithm: Fingerprint Pore Extraction Based On Marker Controlled Watershed Segmentation, but I don't understand step 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, anyone else can explain this algorithm, thanks in advance.

Comment: You should make a link to full algorithm description and write here main steps of algorithm.

Comment: I'm sorry, this paper I download on http://ieeexplore.ieee.org, here another paper for this algorithm: https://www.academia.edu/15883447/Study_of_Local_Binary_Pattern_for_Partial_Fingerprint_Identification, Algorithm:
1. Read the original image. 2.
Develop gradient fingerprint images using appropriate edge detection function. 3.Compute the watershed transform of the gradient fingerprint image without any other processing which gives over segmented image.

Comment: 4. Watershed lines obtained from gradient fingerprint images. Use the obtained watershed line as external markers by calculating regional minima. 5.
Superimpose the foreground marker image on binarized fingerprint image. 6.
 Clean the edges of the markers using edge reconstruction. 7.
 
Compute the background markers. 8.
 
Compute the watershed transform of the function.